# Forgot BIOS supervisor password on an Acer Aspire laptop

Tags: boot, uefi, bios

My computer is an Acer Aspire E5 laptop.

I set a BIOS supervisor password and forgot it.

I tried various methods like biospw code entering thing but after accessing BIOS all options are grey. I took out the laptop's battery for an hour but that didn't work either. I read about jumper shorting but I couldn't find any jumper.

Please suggest a way to change boot priority and access bios!

Comment: Google your make and exact model reset/delete bios password.  Acer sites probably have better advice.  Jumpers usually just small wire to connect two ports, but need to know exact ports to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give some tips on how you can work from here.

First off, removing the battery for an hour is by no means making sure your computer is totally left without any electricity running through it's circuits. Apart from removing the battery, you should also have your laptop unplugged from the power supply (charger) and then press the power button a few times repeatatedly and then continuously for a bunch of seconds (less than a minute). That way we're making sure the computer is totally out of power. The fact that there's no battery, will make anything based on ROM and/or flash-memory, revert to factory settings since there's no juice for it to keep running. That's the general idea of 'removing the battery', and more or less works for all computers.

Regarding your question about clearing CMOS, it's actually pretty simple. All you have to do it find the appropriate pins on the board that say something like 'Clear CMOS' and short-circuit them. To do so, all you need is a conductor, whatever kind. A paper clip as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNX6-dkFey4), or anything that's metal as a matter of fact will do.

Comment: I am not able to locate those pins
There is nothing written on my motherboard